# Looking for Houay den Muang in Laos

Tags: where-on-earth, laos, vientiane

I'm looking for a place called Houay den Muang in Laos, I can't find anything about it on any search engine, does someone know where it is?

Edit: It's probably some place in Vientiane.

Comment: How sure are you of the spelling of the name?

Comment: This page on the Cebuano (!) Wikipedia says it's a river in Laos and gives coordinates: https://ceb.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houay_D%C3%A8nmuang

Comment: @Willeke Unfortunately the romanization of Lao is a complete mess.

Comment: @lambshaanxy, I am trying to establish how far off the spelling can be. I would prefer the local version, if possible.

Comment: @Willeke The spelling is in the filename of a picture, that's all what I have, that's why it's so difficult to find anything...

Comment: @lambshaanxy Thanks, I will see if I can find something about this place!

Comment: If I translate "town" to Laotian, I get meuong. I think muang means town. Another alternative spelling for Houay may be Houy. There are multiple towns that include Houay in the northwest area of the country.

Comment: Can you share the actual photo, which might have some clues?  Feel free to crop/blur out any faces etc.

Comment: There's no real standarization of Lao transliterated into English or French and its vowels overlap ours. Sometimes they reflect French spellings more than English ones due to the colonial history. ເມືອງ is possibly the most common word that could be written "Muang" and can mean anything from village, town, city, state, to country. You say it's in the filename of a picture. What is the picture of? Can you upload it? Is there any context at all? Is it in the countryside or a city? Is it old or recent? Any idea if it was written by a Lao or a westerner?

Answer (score 3):

Found it. It has [a Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/%E0%BA%AB%E0%BB%89%E0%BA%A7%E0%BA%8D%E0%BB%81%E0%BA%94%E0%BA%99%E0%BB%80%E0%BA%A1%E0%BA%B7%E0%BA%AD%E0%BA%87/606417519745711/) but it's a bit unclear as to whether it's a restaurant, a guesthouse, or something else.

The Facebook page has the English subtitle "country house" and a few of the photos are of plates of food but others are of people. Zooming into the map that Facebook provides makes it look like it's within the grounds of Pakpasak Technical College, but often these map pins are just in a random spot of the city. Switching to Google Maps for directions from there, Google associates that spot with the name "Hope Academy". It's in the main central area of Vientiane but I can't really associate it with any main POIs.

Whatever it is, I wouldn't be surprised if it is named after [the town near Savannakhet mentioned by TonyK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/163612/140).

Comment: I think you are probably right. At least I spelt it correctly!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an [intermittent stream](http://www.geonames.org/1657578/houay%20denmuang.html) about 30km from Savannakhet, not Vientiane. As for spelling, you can take your pick from Houay Dènmuang, Houei Den Muong, or Houei Dên Muong. Or  ຫ້ວຍແດນເມຶອງ if I have it right.